# How to insert a datetime from PHP or PDO into a MYSQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, pdo

For some reason the format seems correct, and it will not insert into my database.  If I have it set to Date instead of DateTime and only use Y-m-d it works great for Year-Month-Day.

Table column is datetime:

```
$creation_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$sql = "INSERT INTO table SET creation_date='$creation_date'";

$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$data = $stmt->execute();
```

It echos an example out to:

```
INSERT INTO table SET creation_date='2016-10-22 20:42:11'
```

Comment: what is the type of creation_date column in your table? try to make it timestamp.

Comment: A::: Simple:. If you're going to want to use `Y-m-d H:i:s` then you need to ALTER your column to be DATETIME.

Comment: I just tried that, but doesn't insert...  I used DateTime originally for the Y-m-d H:i:s, but just tried the timestamp which is a different format

Comment: *"no go"* doesn't tell us much really.

Comment: Define "will not insert". We aren't standing over your shoulder and have no idea what is going on with your code

Comment: It is simple, I don't know why the negative votes.  I wrote it simple for a simple answer.

Comment: It's simple. The voting reflects the question's quality.

Comment: Add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE yourtablename;` to your question.

Comment: I wouldn't need the $date for our now time, correct?

Comment: USE SQL's NOW(). Try google..

Comment: I could use NOW(), I was just trying to figure out how to do it with PHP date formatting.

Comment: @MiniFridge I see you are a student. I hope that you'll learn some day that a problem better be solved not by a series of wild guesses but by means of a prior *investigation* that would reveal the actual issue that have to be fixed.

Comment: One reason I also asked this is because the other Stackoverflow questions had the same problem asking this same thing.   They tried the Y-m-d H:i:s format also and that was a common answer, but it didn't work.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I value your advice, I just left a comment with my 2 cents on a low quality question.

Comment: That's really not necessary :(

Comment: @JonStirling ok, removed. But now I know why we have so much cargo cult programmers around

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably failing at some other point, it's hard to tell without seeing your table schema.  Here's a full example which includes table creation and insert, try to duplicate each step, if it still fails I recommend:

1. Try the same queries from mysql command line client (mysql) to see if it's a problem with the PHP library/connection to the db
2. Post your table schema, ideally with all the steps I show below.

```
localhost/test> CREATE TABLE datetest (id smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, \
       ctime DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

localhost/test> SHOW CREATE TABLE datetest;
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table    | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                             |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| datetest | CREATE TABLE `datetest` (
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ctime` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

localhost/test> INSERT INTO datetest SET ctime='2016-10-22 20:42:11';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

localhost/test> SELECT * FROM datetest;
+----+---------------------+
| id | ctime               |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2016-10-22 20:42:11 |
+----+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Another thing to note is that you should stay away from reserved keywords such as `date`. Doesn't look like that's your issue, but something to watch out for.

Comment: I'll do this next time.